# In Visual Basic 6, how do I remove the first character of a string?

Tags: string, vb6

For example, say strWord = "Burger".  I want to create a new string strTrimmedWord, such that it strTrimmedWord = "urger" (B is gone).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Mid` function:

```
strTrimmedWord = Mid(strWord, 2)
```